# Is it necessary for "LDR R0, [R0]" when saving from r15 in arm?

Tags: arm, embedded

From [ARM® Developer Suite Assembler Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Bcfihdhj.html)

> Saving from r15
>
> In general, avoid saving from r15 if possible.
>
> If you do save from r15, the value saved is the address of the current
>   instruction, plus an implementation-defined constant. The constant is
>   always the same for a particular processor.
>
> If your assembled code might be used on different processors, you can
>   find out what the constant is at runtime using code like the
>   following:
>
> SUB R1, PC, #4 ; R1 = address of following STR instruction
>
> STR PC, [R0]   ; Store address of STR instruction + offset,
>
> **LDR R0, [R0]   ; then reload it**
>
> SUB R0, R0, R1 ; Calculate the offset as the difference
>
> If your code is to be assembled for a particular processor, the value
>   of the constant is available in armasm as {PCSTOREOFFSET}.

Comment: See this discussion over on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189442/same-source-and-destination-register-in-ldr

Comment: This is StackExchange "Electrical Engineering" (hardware). It would be better to ask your question in StackOverflow "Code Review."

Comment: This question needs some more details regarding the *question* itself, especially context.

Comment: yes it is necessary, explain how that sequence if instructions would work without that instruction?  How do you get the value of r15 otherwise?   the bigger question is why do you care there really isnt a use case for using r15 in this way nor the offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LDR` reads a word from memory.

`LDR R0, [R0]` reads a word from memory at the address held in `R0`, then stores the value in `R0` (which happens to be the same place the address was stored).

It's not explicitly stated, at least in the part of the documentation you quoted, but before this code snippet you should set R0 to an address that you want it to use as scratch space.

Comment: Sorry, before I couldn't state clearly. I have modified my question. Is it necessary?

Comment: @bumzy Well if you leave it out, then R0 won't contain the value that was stored in the scratch area - instead, it'll still contain the address. So then the next line will do the calculation based on that, and you'll end up with a useless number that doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Saving from `r15` is something you would not normally do, and the architecture specification leaves it open to the implementation how this is implemented.

As the memory interface is an optional stage in opcode processing, and the `ldm` and `stm` instructions need to handle multiple registers, it is entirely possible for an implementation to delay the register read until the instruction reaches the memory interface stage, at which point `r15` may have advanced by more than one instruction.

It is also left to the implementer whether single-register load/store instructions are implemented as single-word load/store with an already decoded register value, or as a load/store multiple with just one bit set.

This really only affects the uncommon case of saving `r15` to memory; all the normal places where you'd use `r15` in an instruction are still well-defined:

- `mov rN, r15` (get PC + 4)
- `ldr rN, [r15, #M]` (load PC-relative)
- `str rN, [r15, #M]` (store PC-relative)
- `ldmia [r13!], {r0-r13,r15}` (load previously stored registers)
- `subs r15, r14, #4` (return from exception)